# Laser diode tests - voltage sweep vs current sweep. What's the difference?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, voltage, semiconductor-physics, electronics

I can't wrap my head around it. There's no current without voltage (except eddy currents), and there's no voltage if there's no current, when you pass the current through a diode.

So why do people sometimes do current sweeps, and sometimes voltage sweeps while testing a laser diode in a lab?

Comment: Your first paragraph is somewhat oversimplified. As a simple example, a battery not connected to anything has a voltage, but there is no current. More generally, devices have more complex characteristic curves of $I$ vs. $U$ than just Ohmian resistors.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are right, the most easy way is to (carefully) increase voltage. However, the problem is that above the threshold voltage the characteristic curve rises up very steeply. Meaning if you are not super carefully you can end up with very large currents that destroy your LED or laser diode. This is why usually LEDs and lasers schould be operated "current-driven" instead of "voltage-driven".

Answer (score 1):

The current in a diode depends roughly exponentially on the voltage. So the only real difference from one to the other is the distribution of the measurement points. If you do a voltage sweep at equidistant points, you will be sampling the current in exponential intervals. If you sample in equal distances in current, you will be taking samples at logarithmic intervals in the voltage.

Depending on what you want to know about the diode, one might be more convenient or precise than the other. Since current and voltage are related by a characteristic of the diode, you can measure that charactaristic separately and convert one into the other.

Comment: What are those parameters, that may be more convenient/precise to measure with one or the other method?

Comment: In the simplest case, if you are interested in light output vs voltage (because in your application it's the voltage you control precisely), you might as well do a sweep over voltage; if you have better control over current, measuring light output vs current will be more helpful. I'm really not enough of an expert on laser diodes to comment on what all the things are you might want to know about such a diode, but this is a rather generic experimental setup.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to control power input to an electric device. One is, indeed, to input stabilized voltage using a source with very small output resistance. Regardless of the load resistance (within engineering limits), the voltage on the output terminals of such a source will be constant.

But sometimes it's useful to know how a device performs when fed with constant current. A [current source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source) is a power source with very large output resistance, so that regardless of the load resistance (again, within engineering limits) the current flowing from one terminal and into another is constant.

Current-driving is important when you want to measure an I-V characteristic that may become a multifunction $I(V)$, rather than a function: e.g. when measuring a thermal breakdown of a p-n junction. OTOH, voltage-driving is appropriate when your device's $V(I)$ would become a multifunction, like the negative differential resistance region of a [tunnel diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_diode).